# Using parSapply to apply function on the rows of the data.table

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table, lapply

I would like to use parLapply/parSapply to do rowvise operations within a data.table,

Here is what I have so far:

```
library(parallel)
library(data.table)


#Generate random data:
n<-10000000
data<-data.table(x=seq(1,n),y=seq(2,n),z=seq(3,n))

#Define random function:
random_function<-function(x){
  x[1]^1+x[2]^2+x[3]^3
}

#Use data.table solution:
system.time(data<-data[,my_new_var_1:=random_function(unlist(.SD)),.SDcols=c("x","y","z"),by=1:nrow(data)])

#use parLapply:
cl<-makeCluster(8)
system.time(data$my_new_var_2<-parSapply(cl,as.list(transpose(data[,c("x","y","z"),with=FALSE])),random_function))
stopCluster(cl)
```

What I want to do is to pass completely general function (I know that sometimes I could optimize my code so that I could avoid rowwise operations). Right now my solutions seems a little bit too clumsy, maybe somebody can suggest a better approach. Even this very clumsy approach on this relatively small dataset gives me some speedup

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your existing data and your real random_function is. Usually one can benefit from parallel execution only with when random_function() is some complex computation.

Your example can be improved even without parallelization:

```
system.time(
    data[, my_new_var_1 := apply(.SD, 1, random_function), 
           .SDcols=c("x","y","z"), 
           by = .I])
```

and using compiler:

```
require(compiler)
random_function <- cmpfun(random_function)

system.time(
    data[, my_new_var_1 := apply(.SD, 1, random_function), 
           .SDcols=c("x","y","z")) # add grouping if needed
```

where `by = .I` or `by = (1:nrow)` does not make sense (and can be omitted now) of course unless you put some more reasonable grouping variable/expression.